# Looping to change urls in a single tabe not working

Tags: javascript

I am having issues trying to get this working. It works but then all it does is take me back to the loop.html file where the script resides.

What im trying to do:
I want the user, me, to input urls seperated my a space.
Then it splits them on the spaces. Then they are arranged in an array.
Then i want it to cycle through each url. Not needing the page to load though. then waiting x amount of time then goes to the next one.

Any help would be appreciated.
My code

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function sleep(ms)
{
    var dt = new Date();
    dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + ms);
    while (new Date().getTime() < dt.getTime());
    return;
}

function launchproducts (form) {
var milli = form.inputbox2.value;
var product_numbers;
var input_from_user = form.inputbox.value;
product_numbers = input_from_user.split(" ",100000);
var one = window.open("about:blank", 'pop');
        for ( var i = 0; i < product_numbers.length; i++) {
            var launch_code = product_numbers[i];
            one.location.href = launch_code;
            sleep(milli);
        }
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">Enter product numbers: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE=""><P>
<METHOD="GET">Enter milliseconds here: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="number" NAME="inputbox2" VALUE="5000"><P>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Start" onClick="launchproducts(this.form)">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: As 555k mentioned, use setTimeout or setInterval. Also, consider using jQuery, it'll be much easier to deal with. PS: Your HTML looks a little "old school", I'd consider moving to XHTML.

Comment: Yeah I know its old school. I'm fairly new to javascript. I've used html quite extensively but not javascript itself. Only ever used snippets etc. This is an attempt to make something myself. As i said i just need it to work.

Comment: Without sticking this into a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net), I can't immediately see what's wrong. I'd suggest using the aforementioned site for sharing code snippets as it lets you run them up. Also, if you're really stuck, try using alert("xxxxx") where xxxx is some meaningful debug information. Remember to check the JavaScript console on your browser of choice as there may be errors!

Comment: There are no errors on the console. Note if i change var launch_code = product_numbers[i]; to var launch_code = product_numbers[1]; it will open the first url as intended. Just to make that clear. So i know it "works" just cant get further than having to put the actual number in.

Comment: product_numbers[1] is the second URL. Is product_numbers[0] valid?

Comment: also using jfiddle it output this  {"error": "Please use POST request"}   Also jeff 0 is valid. Just tried that.

Comment: WTF is a `LANGUAGE="JavaScript"`? Somebody just moved clock by -10 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below works for me (tested on IE8). PLEASE NOTE: I don't consider this to be a "best practice" answer, just a rough rehash of what you've currently got so it actually works and is slightly more readable.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    var product_numbers;
    var myPopup; 
    var itemCounter = 0;

    function launchproducts(form) {
        myPopup = window.open("about:blank", 'pop');
        var milli = form.inputbox2.value;
        var input_from_user = form.inputbox.value;
        product_numbers = input_from_user.split(" ", 100000);

        nextProduct();
        window.setInterval(nextProduct, milli);
    }

    function nextProduct() {
        if (itemCounter >= product_numbers.length) {
            itemCounter = 0;
        }

        myPopup.location.href = product_numbers[itemCounter];
        itemCounter++
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine for me in java as well. This is exactly what i was looking for. I know its no good practice. Just needed something to do the job i needed done. Anyhow thanks for all the help.

Comment: Awesome, you're welcome. Please mark this as the correct answer when you get chance :)

Comment: Done so. I know its hard for people to understand what me or someone else is trying to do. I tried to be as descriptive as possible. If more info was necessary as to why i was doing it this way i could have given it :) anyways this will do exactly what i want the way i need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Delay with  `while (new Date().getTime() < dt.getTime());` is not good

use `setTimeout()` method

Comment: I've tried using settimeout i end up with the same results. At this point in time i just need the code to do what was intended. :(